# How to assign values to the i-th index of a list using a loop?

Tags: r, list, loops, assign

I have integer values which are called `player.i.team.j.coach.k` where `i` ranges over the values 1-11, `j` ranges over the values 1-30 and `k` ranges over the values 1-10.

I'm trying to store the 11 players of each team `j` and coach `k` in a list (each coach will be assigned to 30 teams), for example

```r
team.j.coach.k <- c(player.1.team.j.coach.k, player.2.team.j.coach.k,
                    player.3.team.j.coach.k, player.4.team.j.coach.k,
                    player.5.team.j.coach.k, player.6.team.j.coach.k, 
                    player.7.team.j.coach.k, player.8.team.j.coach.k, 
                    player.9.team.j.coach.k, player.10.team.j.coach.k, 
                    player.11.team.j.coach.k)
```

And I'm trying to use loops for this. The problem is that my code is not working:

First I define empty lists where I will store my teams:

```r
for (j in 1:30) {
  for (k in 1:10) {
    assign(paste0("team.",j,".coach.",k),c())
  }
}
```

So for example

```
> team.1.coach.1
NULL
```

But now the following code throws an error

```r
for (i in 1:11) {
  for (j in 1:30) {
    for (k in 1:10) {
      assign(get(paste0("team.", j, ".coach.", k))[i], 
             get(paste0("player.",i,".team.",j,".coach.",k)))
    }
  }
}
```

and the error is "invalid first argument". Alternatively, the following code throws an error as well

```r
for (i in 1:11) {
  for (j in 1:30) {
    for (k in 1:10) {
      get(paste0("team.", j, ".coach.", k))[i] <- get(paste0("player.", i, ".team.", j, ".coach.", k))
    }
  }
}
```

Where the error is "target of assignment expands to non-language object".

Note: I created the objects `player.i.team.j.coach.k` using `assign()` and a loop, that's why they are stored in a list yet.

Comment: This question is not very clear.  Have you thought about using a single 3D array instead of multiple objects?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 my question is how to store in a list the 11 players of each team (and corresponding coach) using a loop. I posted two attempts which failed.

Comment: Maybe something like `myList <- list; for(i in ...) ... mylist[paste("team",j,"coach",k, sep=".")] <- someStuff`. This should construct a named list during the loop. correction, thanks to C8H10N4O2.

Comment: @user322778 this is just not a good programming practice because you are limiting what you can do with the data.  A better practice would be to make one or more data.frames of coaches, teams, and players, or you could make lists of lists, or you could create some basic S3 objects if you were so inclined,

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I understand what you mean, I created the objects player.i.team.j.coach.k using a loop and assign() but I don't know how to store them in a dataframe in the same loop. That's why I'm trying to paste names and numbers together now

Comment: Your question has been asked numerous times already. As a beginner you should never use `assign`. Better approaches have been mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @rOLAND Ok, I thought my question was somehow different, I read a couple of asnwers in similar questions but couldn't adapt them to my situation

Comment: You're asking for feedback re downvotes so: I downvoted because I don't think the question is useful, wouldn't want people getting the idea that embedding numbers into strings like you say you're doing is remotely good practice. That doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't post on SO, nor does it say anything about you, really, just about the ideas in your post; I'm just using the voting system for what it's designed for.

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure whatever you're doing here would be better handled by a data.frame (or a few of them), which is more than adequate as a structure for most R users' data. Btw, please at least read what Spacedman says before deciding to get offended. You should become familiar with some basic data structures built into R before trying to reinvent them.

Comment: @Imo your suggestion doesn't work, when I try it in a loop the symbol <- yields the error "target of assignment expands to non-language object"

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the feedback. I certainly don't know how to define a dataframe while doing a loop at the same time. If I knew this then my objects player.i.team.j.coach.k would be stored in a list already and I wouldn't be asking this question. And I'm not offended, I just thought the downvotes were unfair but you've explained the reasons

Comment: Okay, I would expect something like: `coach_assignmentDF = data.frame(coach_id = 1:10, team_id = 1:30)` and `player_assignmentDF = data.frame(player_id = 1:(11*30), team_id = 1:30)` with unique integer IDs for each agent/unit. To get familiar with this way of thinking in R, I'd suggest Hadley's paper on tidy data: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Comment: @Frank I see your point and I've handled that kind of dataframes quite often but I think it's not applying to my situation this time. Actually my objects player.i.team.j.coach.k come from SQL queries which I found simpler to obtain thanks to assign(). To simulate my code, you could try the following for(a in 1:11){for (b in 1:30){for (c in 1:10){assign(paste0("player.",a,".team.",b,".coach.",c),a+b+c)}}} but taking into account that "a+b+c" is in fact a SQL query in my case

Comment: Ok, well your SQL database should presumably have such tables (for players and coaches). If, for some reason, you only get one `(a, b, c)` tuple at a time from SQL, it still seems better to store a list `L` of such tuples and then bind them together, with `do.call(rbind, lapply(L, as.data.frame))` or `data.table::rbindlist(L)` or similar.

Comment: @Frank I have more than 2000 of such tuples! That's why I used a loop combined with assign(). If I could use something like rbind inside this loop then I would solve my problem. It's complicated to explain in the comments though, but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135096/discussion-on-question-by-user322778-how-to-assign-values-to-the-i-th-index-of-a).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, after struggling so much and watching my reputation going down the toilet due to several downvotes, I managed to solve my problem. I used a variable `count` inside my loop to store everything as a single list, and then splitting my list into my desired lists:

```
my.list<-c()

count=0

for (c in 1:10){for (b in 1:30){for (a in 1:11){assign(paste0("player.",a,".team.",b,".coach.",c),a+b+c);count=count+1;my.list[count]<-get(paste0("player.",a,".team.",b,".coach.",c))}}}
```

And now I split `my.list` to get the lists that I want:

```
for (c in 1:10){for (b in 1:30){assign(paste0("team.",b,".coach.",c),my.list[(11*(b+30*(c-1))-10):(11*(b+30*(c-1)))])}}
```

And I get exactly what I want:

```
> for (b in 1:30){for (c in 1:10){print(get(paste0("team.",b,".coach.",c)))}}
 [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 [1] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 [1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 [1] 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 [1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 [1] 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 [1] 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 [1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 [1] 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 [1] 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 [1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 [1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 [1] 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 [1] 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 [1] 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
 [1] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
 [1] 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
 [1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
 [1] 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
 [1] 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 [1] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 [1] 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
 [1] 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
 [1] 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
 [1] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = c(3,5,6)
x[2] = 9
x  # [1] 3 9 6
```

Did this help?  (Re- assign a value to the i-th index of the list without assign and using a loop)

Comment: In R if you do ?assign it shows the help for an assign function.

Comment: Hmm no, this method fails when I try it in a loop, also assign() fails